# MSVC2019 ifstream unusable

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

Not really a question, but more of a heads-up: streams in MS' version of STL are pretty much unusable, except for the most basic tasks.

I've been trying to do basically the following (with an instance of ifstream as the actual argument):

```
void test(std::istream& is)
{
   auto pos1 = is.tellg();
   is.read(some_buffer, some_size);
   auto pos2 = is.tellg();
   assert(is.gcount() == some_size);
   assert(pos2 == pos1 + is.gcount());   // fails intermittently, with a difference of 1 byte!
}
```

No problems with this code in GCC!

Comment: Educated guess: you are reading a text file - or at least, you are opening your stream in text mode - and are encountering `\r\n` pairs that are automatically converted to `\n`. If you want to read and count bytes as-is, open the stream in binary mode.

Comment: From C11 standard: "The `ftell` function obtains the current value of the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream. For a binary stream, the value is the number of characters from the beginning of the file. For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the `fseek` function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the `ftell` call; **the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read.**" Emphasis mine.

Comment: You were bang on! Opening the file in binary mode did the job!
I guess I should start wearing ashes in my hair for a week, or look for another job as interior decorator... Good thing you're taking time answering random Qs on SO, so idiots like me can keep their jobs!